# Clicking on Chrome-generated pop-ups doesn't work most of the time. Why?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, popups

Clicking on Chrome-generated pop-ups such as the one shown in the screenshot below doesn't work most of the time: the mouse click is ignored. Why? If I hit  <kbd>ENTER</kbd> it works fine.

[image]

I use Chrome on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume that old software was the issue. Upgrading the operating system to  Windows 10 and Chrome to the latest version (117) while keeping the same Chrome extensions solved the issue.